# Instanton Counting (Tachikawa's Review) and "Hilbert Space"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, instantons

I'm reading [this review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7121.pdf) on instanton counting. I cannot understand in section 3 how supersymmetric Hilbert spaces come about. For instance in section 3.1.1, covering the supersymmetric particle on $\mathbb{C}^2$, he writes

$$
\mathcal{H}_{\mathrm{susy}}=\bigoplus_{n,m\geq0}\mathbb{C}z^nw^m\ \ .
$$

What does he mean? If it is a free particle on $\mathbb{C}^2$, why aren't its states labelled by their continuous momenta? Why is the trace made upon these "states"? States of what?

Going further it is even more obscure for me. Can someone provide a derivation of the "susy Hilbert spaces" for the particle on the sphere with magnetic flux, and on the quotient $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Maybe $\mathbb{C}^2$ is phase space and he's using holomorphic quantization? It's hard to tell.